# Shuffle ArrayList

Tags: java, android, collections, android-recyclerview, shuffle

I have two `RecyclerView` and one `ArrayList` called **collections**, I'm trying to shuffling this `ArrayList` and get 12 items of it.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<CollectionsModel> collections) {
    super.onPostExecute(collections);
    if (isAdded() && getActivity() != null) {
        setAdapterForRecyclerView(collections);
         setAdapterForRecyclerViewBestCollections(shuffleCollection(collections));
    }
}
```

**Shuffle Method :**

```
public List<CollectionsModel> shuffleCollection(List<CollectionsModel> collectionsModelList) {
    java.util.Collections.shuffle(collectionsModelList);
    return collectionsModelList;
}
```

**Adapter Method for RecyclerView 1 :**

```
private void setAdapterForRecyclerViewBestCollections(List<CollectionsModel> collectionHelper) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        arrayListCollections.add(collectionHelper.get(i));
    }
    /*rest of code*/
}
```

**Adapter Method for RecyclerView 2 :**

```
private void setAdapterForRecyclerView(final List<CollectionsModel> wlls) {
    if (myAdapter == null) {
        myAdapter = new MyAdapterCollection(wlls, getActivity(), new RecyclerViewClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, Wallpaper wallpaper) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, CollectionsModel collectionsModel) {

            }
        }, R.layout.collection_item);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
    } else {
        int position = myAdapter.getItemCount();
        myAdapter.getItems().addAll(wlls);
        myAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(position, position);
    }
}
```

**My Issue :**

When I run the app, I see `RecyclerView` 1 and `RecyclerView` 2 both of them randomized (With same order).

**What I want :**

I want to see random items order in `RecyclerView` 1 and normal order `RecyclerView` 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you are passing list object to `setAdapterForRecyclerView(collections);`

After that you are passing same list object to `setAdapterForRecyclerViewBestCollections(shuffleCollection(collections));`

And then shuffling the object (in both the methods you are using same object and shuffle will reflects to both `RecyclerView1` and `RecyclerView2`

Create new `List` object and return that after shuffling, so that you will see two different order in `RecyclerView1` and `RecyclerView2`

```
public List<CollectionsModel> shuffleCollection(List<CollectionsModel> collectionsModelList) {
    List<CollectionsModel> shuff = new ArrayList<>(collectionsModelList);
    java.util.Collections.shuffle(shuff);
    return shuff;
}
```